# Генератор в рекурсивной функции

Tags: php

Рекурсивная функция возвращает все папки из директории `C:\Test`, кроме вложенных. Что необходимо изменить, чтобы генератор `yield` возвращал все папки, включая вложенные?

```
function dirFinder ($folder)
{
    $all_in_folder = scandir($folder);
    foreach ($all_in_folder as $object) {
        if ($object == '.' || $object == '..') continue;
        $path_to_object = "$folder" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$object";
        if (is_dir($path_to_object)) {
            yield $path_to_object;
            dirFinder($path_to_object);               
        }
    }
}

foreach (dirFinder('C:\Test') as $value) {
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dirFinder($path_to_object);
```

просто возвращает в тело цикла генератор,
но при этом ничего не возвращается из первичного вызова функции dirFinder('c:\test');

замените эту строчку на

```
foreach (dirFinder($path_to_object) as $subFolder) {
    yield $subFolder;
}
```